# Emoji button in android applications

Tags: android, emoji

I am developing android chat application and I want to add emoji button that if the user clicks on it open a page that contains all emojis (similar to Whatsapp Emoji page or telegram Emoji page), is there a library or JAR that provide all emojis ?? or Should I Implement them hard-coded in my application?

[image: here is Emoji button]

This page is what I want to implement:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) can be used but is discontinued, so, for now, this [emojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat) can be used which is latest and this is from google so no need to worry about any problems.. :)

Comment: how can I get all emojis using this emojiCompat ?